# Call ASP.Net Page Method using jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Here i am pasting my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var items = [{text: 'Onion', value: '1'},
                         {text: 'Ketchup', value: '2'},
                         {text: 'Mayonnaise', value: '3'},
                         {text: 'Pickles', value: '4'},
                         {text: 'Tomato', value: '5'},
                         {text: 'Patatoes', value: '6'},
                         {text: 'Sausage', value: '7'},
                         {text: 'Lettuce', value: '8'},
                         {text: 'Pepper', value: '9'}
                        ];

            $('#myCheckList').checkList({
                listItems: items,
                onChange: selChange
            });

            function selChange(){
                var selection = $('#myCheckList').checkList('getSelection');

                $('#selectedItems').text(JSON.stringify(selection));
            }


        });
    </script>
```

I want in `var items=` ,it will take a method i.e `getItems()` and that method is written in ItemDAL.cs(DAL layer) and it is getting all the items list from database.How to do this? Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: You should create an ASP.NET Web API service that can access your ItemDAL.cs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a c# representation of your object:

```
public class SelectItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then a page behind web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<SelectItem> GetItems()
    {
        var items = new List<SelectItem>();
        // look up db items and populate from your Dal          
        return items;
    }
```

Then your js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                var items;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetItems",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {

                        items = msg.d;

                    }
                });

            $('#myCheckList').checkList({
                listItems: items,
                onChange: selChange
            });

            function selChange(){
                var selection = $('#myCheckList').checkList('getSelection');

                $('#selectedItems').text(JSON.stringify(selection));
            }


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Its not working properly... in web method its working properly..but in jquery its nt accepting the items value..where should i write that web methods..can you tell me?

Comment: You can do a jquery for each to populate it instead. I just left the jquery as it was. I can update the question with the fore each later today. Not on a computer at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure what the checklist is that you are using but this is an example of how I populate a dropdown list in a success call, I hope it is of some help:


                                                var subs = msg.d;
      // empty selection
      var $ddlSubCategory = $('#ddlSubCategory');
      $ddlSubCategory.empty();

      $.each(subs, function (index, sub) {
       $ddlSubCategory.append($('<option/>', {
        value: sub.Id,
        text: sub.Text
       }));
      });

Comment: How to call a webmethod in jquery? today i posted dis question...der i hv given the details..can u answer?